# How to use ASP tags with stringbuilder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, stringbuilder

I am using `StringBuilder` to build a page in ASP.NET. I've done this several times without any problems, but now I need to put a string that has ASP's inside it, mount is not the problem but the page does not work.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.AppendLine("<div class=""col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"">")
    sb.AppendLine("<img class=""img-responsive"" src=""imagens/208/1005/Clientes.png""/>")
    sb.AppendLine("<asp:ImageButton ID=""ImageButton1"" runat=""server"" ImageUrl=""~/Imagens/Icon-trash2.png"">")
    sb.AppendLine("</div>")

    comandos.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

But the HTML it generates is giving error (see below) ..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOCp4.png

Comment: You can't do that. Think about the lifecycle of Web Forms. Why do you need to dynamically create this control? Why don't you just create the control directly in your markup, then selectively show/hide it when needed?

Comment: "I've done this several times without any problems"  That's pretty doubtful, you can't create ASP.Net server controls like this.